# Is there any easy way to know my daily average reputation gain?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm interested into knowning my daily average reputation gain, is there any easy way to know it?

Comment: your total rep / how many days you've been a member? You can find the date you joined by hovering over the ["member for 3years  6 months"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1225328/sp00m)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if using SEDE is considered to stretch the definition of easy but if you're fine with that, this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/356906?UserId=1225328) will give you your average reputation gain per day.

```sql
select reputation
      , creationdate
      , (select create_date
        from sys.databases
        where database_id = db_id()) as last_sede_update
      , reputation /
        datediff(d
        , creationdate
        , (select create_date
        from sys.databases
        where database_id = db_id())) as Avg_gain
from users
where id = ##userid:int##
```

The query takes into account the last date SEDE was updated. Under normal conditions that is weekly, on <s>Monday</s>Sunday.

Comment: It updates [on Sundays, actually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234390/sede-faq-small-discrepancy-update-day). I know it *says* Monday on the page, but the normal updates always take place on Sunday. The most recent update was delayed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters somehow I got [confused](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/commit/163d09fb5e9e584c6af060024b88e970567fc945)  about the [correct](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/commit/92c1b034518e90e06c3e5768e480b07f50358d10) day...

Comment: Wait, what, you changed it then changed it back again? :-D

Answer (score 2):

Go to your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=profile) and paste the following code in the console:

```js
var startDate = new Date(document.querySelector('.user-links li .icon-history + span').title)
var rep = parseInt(document.querySelector('.reputation').innerText.replace(',',''))

var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; 
var days = Math.round(Math.abs((startDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime())/(oneDay)))

var dailyAvg = Math.round(rep / days * 100) / 100
alert('Your daily avergae is ' + dailyAvg + ' pts/day')
```